# Как реализовать публичный статический метод который возвращает итератор по регистру продуктов который должен быть реализован анонимным классом?

Tags: php

Итератор должен быть реализован анонимным классом.

```
<?php
namespace lesson2;

header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');


class User{
private $name;
private $balance;

function __construct($name,$balance){
    $this->name = $name;
    $this->balance = $balance;
}

public function getName(){
    return $this->name;
}

public function getBalance(){
    return $this->balance;
}

public function __toString(){
    return "У пользователя ".$this->getName()." сейчас на счету ".$this->getBalance()."<br/>";
}

public function giveMoney($user, $amount){
    if($amount > $this->balance){
        return 'Недостаточно средств!'."<br/>";
    }
    else{
        $this->balance -= $amount;
        $user->balance += $amount;
        return "Пользователь ".$this->name." перечислил ".$amount." пользователю ".$user->name."<br/>";
    }

}

}

abstract class Product{
private $name;
private $price;
private $owner;
static private $products=array();

function __construct($name, $price, $owner){
    $this->name = $name;
    $this->price = $price;
    $this->owner = $owner;
}

public function setOwner(User $user){
    $this->owner = $user;
}

public static function registerProduct($product){
    if (in_array($product, self::$products, true)) {
        echo 'Введены одинаковые продукты '.'</br>';
    }
    else{
        array_push(self::$products,$product);
    }
}
}

class Processor extends Product{
private $frequency;
public function __construct($name, $price, $owner,$frequency)
{
    parent::__construct($name, $price, $owner);
    $this->frequency=$frequency;
}

}

class Ram extends Product{
private $type;
private $memory;
public function __construct($name, $price, $owner, $type, $memory)
{
    parent::__construct($name, $price, $owner);
    $this -> type = $type;
    $this -> memory = $memory;
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Создаём и возвращаем анонимный класс реализующий дефолтный интерфейс итератора https://www.php.net/manual/ru/class.iterator.php, также не забываем передать ему в конструктор наш массив.

```
class Product
{
    /**
     * @var mixed[]
     */
    static private array $products = [
        'Хлеб',
        'Консервы',
        'Энергетический напиток',
        'Водка',
        'Колбаса'
    ];

    public static function makeIterator(): Iterator
    {
        return new class (self::$products) implements Iterator {
            private int $position = 0;
            private array $array;

            public function __construct(array $array)
            {
                $this->array = array_values($array);
            }

            public function rewind(): void
            {
                $this->position = 0;
            }

            public function current()
            {
                return $this->array[$this->position];
            }

            public function key(): int
            {
                return $this->position;
            }

            public function next(): void
            {
                ++$this->position;
            }

            public function valid(): bool
            {
                return isset($this->array[$this->position]);
            }
        };
    }
}
```